# PostScript execution of nested procedures

Tags: stack, interpreter, execution, procedure, postscript

(I'm back with yet another question :-) )

Given the following PostScript code:

```
/riverside { 5 pop } def
/star { 6 pop 2 {riverside} repeat } def
star
```

I'm wondering how nested procedures should be handled. *(I'm creating my own interpreter).*
When I execute the star procedure, halfway it finds a nameObjec(riverside) and replaces it with an executable array containing the values from the riverside procedure and executes them. 
If I execute the repeat operator the interpreter crashes because there is only one item left on the stack.

Should I actually execute an executable array (=procedure) directly when I'm already in an executable array (=prodecure), or should the executable arrays (=procedures) always be pushed on the (operand?/execution?)stack? or only be executed by another operator?
How many times should this riverside be executed? (2 or 3 times?) I guess 2?

For your information: this is the situation that I have when I execute *star* on the 3rd line (see the ERROR):

```
% begin execute 3rd line (star)
% OP = operand stack
% EX = execution stack    

% handle 6
OP: 6
EX: star

% handle pop (removes 6 from OP)
OP: -
EX: star

% handle 2
OP: 2
EX: star

% set the riverside executable array on the EX, execute the values
OP: 2
EX: star riverside

% repeat operator:
CRASH, only one item on the OP left, but repeat operator requires 2 operands.
OP: 5
EX: 

% end
```

Please shine a light on this matter, because it is somewhat complex/confusing :-)

**Update:**
another code sample might be this one:

```
/starside
{ 72 0 lineto
currentpoint translate
-144 rotate } def

/star
{ moveto
currentpoint translate
4 {starside} repeat
closepath
gsave
.5 setgray fill
grestore
stroke } def

200 200 star

showpage
```

when the interpreter tokenizes */star { moveto ...* if it encounters the nested *{starside}* how will that be treated? (+ what if there was *{starside 5 2 mul pop}* instead of only *{starside}* ?)

Comment: Ken covers the scanning part. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6951850/733077) describes one way of implementing the `repeat` operator to interact properly with the operand stack.

Comment: so you push the repeat operator token also on the exc.stack. hmmm great example :-)

Comment: There's another style where you use a separate *internal* operator call `@loopcontinue` or something like that. But I found it much simpler to use `cvx`, a literal procedure, and the original operator. This works for `repeat`, `loop`, `for`, and `forall` with arrays and strings, but not with a dictionary. To do `forall` with a dictionary, I had to resort to an internal operator which returned a smaller chunk of the dictionary data. There's another looping operator, `image` that works by recursively calling the entire interpreter to execute the procedure body.

Comment: Some good resources on PS interpreter internals: [Rae A. Earnshaw, Workstations and Publication Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Workstations-Publication-Systems-Rae-Earnshaw/dp/0387965270/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1368842790&sr=8-2&keywords=earnshaw+rae+workstations+publication+systems) and [Frank Merritt Braswell, Inside Postscript](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Postscript-Frank-Merritt-Braswell/dp/093815110X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1368843730&sr=1-1&keywords=frank+merritt+braswell+inside+postscript).

Comment: oh thanks luser droog! very useful information!

Comment: I'm sure you would've found them eventually. There's not much out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to look at section 3.5.3 of the PLRM. Although this deals with a simple executable array the concept is the same. When the token scanner encounters a '{' it starts to build an executable array. Until it reaches a matching '}' token the scanner simply stores what it encounters on the operand stack. When it encounters the matching '{' then the objects are converted into an executable array (and stored on the operand stack)

In the case of the scanner encountering an executable name, it stores the *name* on the operand stack. It does not execute the name, nor does it even perform lookup on it to retrieve the associated object.

So immediately before the execution of '}' in your example, the operand stack would contain twp objects, the '{' opening array, and the executable name riverside. When you encounter the '}' then the scanner creates the actual executable array and stores it on the operand stack. (Note, implementation details vary here)

So immediately before the execution of 'repeat' you would have two objects on the stack, the counter and an executable array containing a single executable name.

You don't look up the name until the executable array containing the name is executed.

This might make it clearer:

```
%!
/test {(This is my initial string\n) print} def
2 {test} repeat
2 {test} /test {(This is my second string\n) print} def repeat
```

Notice that I've redefined 'test' *after* creating the executable array containing the executable name 'test', yet the execution uses the later definition of test. As you can see, its vitally important not to do name lookup too early!

Comment: I'll have a look at your information. My code works for normal procedures, but not when they are nested. like { .... { ... } ... }

Comment: +1 for "vitally important not to do name lookup too early". *Delayed binding* is one of the fundamental concepts of PostScript, according to [this 1986 interview with John Warnock](http://programmersatwork.wordpress.com/john-warnock/).

Comment: @luserdroog : is there a way to contact you? (email?)

Comment: @juFo sure! luser.droog@gmail.com